# What is the name of the district that is considered to be the city center of Rome?

Tags: security, hostels, rome, landmarks

I'm planing to go to Rome for a visit next month. I'm searching for the city center of Rome so I can book an hostel close to it.

The places that I want to visit really don't know, Rome is full of gorgeous stuff I have read about, but I think all these stuff can be caught from the public transportation from the city center, **right?** **(I don't want to take taxis, I will just use public transportation)**. That's why I want to know the city center.

Comment: Rome is a pretty spread out city, so there isn't a single centre: there's the Roman centre (Forum, colosseum, etc), the Vatican, the modern political centre, shopping, etc, etc.

Comment: As it stands the question is a bit too broad. What are your criteria for the hostel/accommodation? Is it just a question of being close to tourist attractions?

Comment: @JoErNanO no he wants to know what  the center is called. Like how in NYC you'd say, look for a place in Manhattan, or Downtown in Vancouver, or San Telmo etc in Buenos Aires.  Unfortuantely as others have pointed out, there's no single center (much like Tokyo)

Comment: @MarkMayo Ok my bad. Editing and voting to reopen.

Comment: I will be in Rome next month for few days, and the way I book hotel from booking.com is, set the filter 7+ reviews, only private rooms only, and also open google map of rome in another tab, compare the location, sort options by price, and then select. This time I selected the one near Termini, although there is one more metro stop right out of hotel.

Comment: IMO, The center of Rome from a tourist point of view is the Centro Storico (around the piazza de fiori); Rome is very walkable.

Answer (score 12):

Transportation and getting around wise, your best bet would be to stay somewhere near the Termini train station. That is where the long haul trains arrive, and you are pretty much 10-20 minutes away from pretty much every major attraction. Being close to the Termini station can be helpful if you plan to go/come from Florence, or Civitavecchia, where the trains arrive at around the mid night, and there would be no metro to use at that time.

I stayed in a couple hostels during my stay, and I really liked one near the Vittorio Emanuele metro station. I'm no way affiliated with them, but [here](https://www.booking.com/hotel/it/discoveryhostel.en-gb.html) is a link if you'd like to try it out. The staff was very friendly, but note that the surroundings were some Indian restaurants and one would say it's a dodgy neighborhood. I didn't care about that.

For a different environment, try to book somewhere in the north western region, where the Vatican is located at. There is no metro line too close (the closest is Ottaviano), but I never felt any tired walking from a nearby metro station.

There are trams and buses that connect an otherwise star-like metro system. It's not the smoothest way to travel (there were two stations out of service during my visit, although they provided alternative transport via a bus). The tourist pass wasn't that worth it, but 1, 2 or 3 day transport cards were well worth it.

You can read a lot more about there from this nice [page](http://wikitravel.org/en/Rome). 
Have fun, and be safe!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found this hostel https://www.booking.com/hotel/it/tokyo.html?label=gen173nr-17CAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaLsBiAEBmAExuAEEyAEE2AEB6AEB-AEC;sid=9d643ac47565468b48771ec3bca0149a;dcid=1;checkin=2016-02-17;checkout=2016-02-21;dist=0;group_adults=1;group_children=0;no_rooms=1;room1=A;sb_price_type=total;srfid=926e54add0ec420c30aec679104731b7e319d0f4X2;type=total;ucfs=1& do you think it is close to the city center? plus is this close to this indian place? also what did you mean by "doggy" ?

Comment: kindly would you check the hostel i sent you please ?

Comment: Dodgy, I meant. It was a bit dark in the night (no many street lights), and there were some street sellers selling some used mobile phones (looks like stolen ones). I could walk to the Termini station from there, so I'd say it's pretty close to the center. Te hostel you linked looks good too, but a bit expensive IMHO.

Comment: @sarah If you want recommendations on hostels, try the likes of hostelworld. (and maybe TripAdvisor, but I don't think their hostel coverage is great). We don't really do individual product recommendations/reviews on this site.

Comment: It would have been better if I did not mention a hostel in first place. @drat - thanks for raising the concerns. I have no any affiliation with the hostel or the booking site. Please see my reply in your question too.

Comment: @AyeshK well yesterday the price was 45 euros for 4 nights, i don't know why today suddenly it became 110 euros :( :(, anyway, just to be sure (and I 'm sorry for askign again), this hotel is close to the city center, and the name of the city center is `Termini` right? and this place is not dangerous.